# Set the dock hover name in mac os x?

Tags: osx

I normally have many Emacs instances open (emacs 27.1 in Mac OS X Catalina), each opened from iterm2, based on different environment variable setups (they refer to different source control snapshots in a company custom source control).

I end up with many individual icons in the dock, each looking exactly the same and each having the exact same name when you hover over them ("Emacs"). So it's tricky to find the one I want.

It could be quicker if I could change the hover name. Not sure of the official title for this name. I have seen some postings that call it dockname for Java.

Is there a way, from within Emacs (Lisp), to set that name?

Comment: You pose multiple questions here, which means the question risks being deleted as lacking focus. Please pose only one question per question.

Comment: Done, thanks. Split it into two questions.